# Copy specific portion of lines from a text file to separate file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have one file in which i want to search a text and then i need to find start and end block. Then need to copy to another file. I have multiple statements in the same file.

below is an example.

```
1: Start
2: hello 
3: Hello world 
4: Good Morning 
5: End
```

I want to search "Good Morning" and then i want to copy text between start and end block to new file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also do you want the numbers included in your search or no?

Comment: IF - and that is a big IF - your text is formatted as shown _all the time_, then take a look at the `-Context` parameter of `Select-String`. that accepts one or two [int]s for "lines before, lines after". so `-Context 3,1` will grab the 3 lines before the matching line AND the 1 line after it. [*grin*] ///// take a look at `Get-Help Select-String -Parameter Context` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

With a regular expression with [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) you can find the match
(see the [regex live](https://regex101.com/r/WEafTC/2) with different escaping `\`=` )

With your text in a file `.\sample.txt`, this snippet:

```
#requires -Version 3.0
[regex]::match((Get-Content .\Sample.txt -raw),"(?sm)(?<=^Start`r?`n).*?Good Morning.*?(?=`r?`nEnd)").Value
#                                                    \  lookbehind /                   \lookahead/
```

returns

```
hello
Hello world
Good Morning
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will get you what you want. First I grabbed the contents of the txt file and put it in the `$doc` variable.
Then using powershell's native "text" search feature I look for the string containing "Good Morning" and if that is true then using regex I grab all contents between the start and end text and create a new txt file with those contents. Below is the code.

```
$doc = Get-Content C:\Scripts\test.txt

      if(Select-String -InputObject $doc -Pattern "Good Morning" -SimpleMatch){
        $contents = [regex]::Match($doc,'(?is)(?<=\b\d: Start\b).*?(?=\b\d: End\b)')
            New-Item -Path C:\Scripts -Name newtest.txt -ItemType File -Value $contents
      }
      Else{
         Write-Host "Nothing Found"
      }
```

Comment: I tried below code. it generates output file but its blank. can we add like command instead of is start end? 

$doc = Get-Content "C:\Users\a154499\Desktop\testPS.txt"

      if(Select-String -InputObject $doc -Pattern "dwsn14626" -SimpleMatch){
        $contents = [regex]::Match($doc,'(?is)(?<=\b\d: Schedule\b).*?(?=\b\d: End\b)')
            New-Item -Path C:\tmp1 -Name newtest.txt -ItemType File -Value $contents
      }
      Else{
         Write-Host "Nothing Found"
      }

Comment: It is not working for me. i have many recursive entries in the file. will this script help to show multiple section in file?

Comment: It worked if i have only one occurrence but not working in my case because i have multiple occurrence of schedule and end statements.
 
$doc = Get-Content "C:\testPS.txt"

      if(Select-String -InputObject $doc -Pattern "DWSN14624"){
        $contents = [regex]::Match($doc,'(?sm)(?=SCHEDULE).*?DWSN14624.*?(?=END).*')
            New-Item -Path C:\tmp1 -Name newtest.txt -ItemType File -Value $contents
      }
      Else{
         Write-Host "Nothing Found"
      }

Comment: Separating the trigger `Good Morning` from the `Start`,`End` markers could lead to false positives in a more complex scenario than  originally given. @Saurabh Did I guess right the leadinng numbers colon are **not** part of the file? You should append a more real life example to your question.